# The method getDatabase(String) is undefined for the type MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to follow the [MongoDB Driver Quick Start](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) tutorial, but I get this error from VS Code: The method getDatabase(String) is undefined for the type MongoClient Java(67108964).

I think I did exactly what the tutorial says, this is my code:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

public class DbController{

    static MongoCollection<Document> coll;

    public DbController(){
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient
            (new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
    coll = database.getCollection("mycoll");
    }
    ...
}
```

I added this to my build.gradle:

```
compile("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.3")
```

And this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So what did I miss? Everything else works just fine.

Comment: are you sure the dependencies are correctly loaded?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have set up a mongoDB at "mongodb://localhost:27017" right?

Comment: @Filip123go how is that relevant for the compiler to find a method in the MongoDB jar?

Comment: @Stultuske yes, I think so, everything else woudn't work either, would it?

Comment: @IrinaFrosch for all we know a different version is loaded.

Comment: @Stultuske what exactly do you mean? the mongodb-driver?